# Summation of input values of two different columns calculated and displayed in the third column (same row) in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, calculation

I want to calculate the total of inputs of two different columns and display the total in the third column. Using ngmodel and template driven form in angular material table. Below is the format

| 1st | 2nd | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed now with :

```
getTotal(row:any) {
   return (parseInt(row.first) + parseInt(row.second));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my accessing the **row** instead of **element** in *matCellDef and calling a method to calculate total.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="total">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Total</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{getTotal(row)}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

In ts file:

```
getTotal(row) {
     return row.first + row.second;
  }
```

See the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-material-table-edited?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: hi, thanks . I am using Ngmodel. So the values should be coming from input fields that user inputs.

Comment: In that case, you can calculate total using input variables. No need to use row.